# Spurious periods of stars

Tags: observational-astronomy, binary-star, photometry, variable-star, hipparcos

What exactly is meant by *spurious periods of stars*? E. Tanner writes in *[Spurious Periods in Spectroscopic Binaries](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1948JRASC..42..177T)* in 1948

[image]

Furthermore: Can spurious periods be produced by aliasing, and how can they be handled? I read about this that these periods can be detected while using Robust variogram estimator in [this paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1999A%26AS..136..421E/abstract).

Comment: Are you referring to this http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1948JRASC..42..177T

Comment: Yes, I am referring to this concept.

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE! To avoid down- and close-votes, please follow the guidelines [ask]. It would be great if you could edit-in the reference @JamesK mentioned plus the relevant quote from it.

Comment: To give you an idea what I am talking about, I edit your question a bit, but further improvements (and details) from your side would be beneficial.

Comment: Thank you for your editing, I also edit it according to my understandings.

Comment: Uhm... in the following paragraph that very paper explains exactly what the author mean with "spurious periods". In essence it's a polite way of "wrongly measured" or "badly analysed, thus wrong"

Comment: Hmm, got it, thanks

Comment: @JunaidIhsan yes I also am pretty sure that spurious is just polite for erroneous, i.e. bad data. But your question "Can spurious periods be produced by aliasing?" is a great one! You can consider just posting a short answer here yourself explaining that you now agree with comments that "spurious is just polite for erroneous" and you can accept it also, then post a new question "Can spurious periods be produced by aliasing?", or you could just modify this one and remove all the references to the old paper, or just say that it's background, what got you thinking about ailiasing.

Comment: You could also ask a question like "Have there been famous or demonstrative examples of aliasing leading to spurious periods in more modern settings than this paper from 1948?"

Comment: Spurious periods caused by aliasing happen all the time especially in Fourier based period searching. Sometimes they can be hard to disentangle from the "real" period especially if the "real" period is near a multiple of nice fraction of a day. One test is to do a Fourier transform of the observation times, see if the proposed period is also indicated by the spectrogram/periodogram. This is the window function. The other term to look out for are beat periods. Can't point you a specific modern example. Most researchers are now aware of the problem(s).